# Recognize Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8

The new Ubuntu 14 point something doesn't recognize Windows 8.1 in the installation process. I would like to install it side-by-side, but since the backdoor way includes creating my own partitions on the drive and a bunch of stuff I am not familiar with nor comfortable doing, I will not be installing it. Is there any fix for this that is coming out?
Thank you for your time and I hope you have a great day!

Comment: Install it in virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an Ext4 partition inside the win 8.1 disk, to do this use Gparted, after creating the partition boot ubuntu installation and install it in the ext4 partition,

Give some feedbak if it worked or not.